# Python: create file if file does not exist in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm getting a list of files in a project, which can all range from `src/app.ts` to `src/component/app/app.ts`. What I'm looking to do is:

- loop over each file in the list,
- see if it matches a pattern of a specific config,
- and if the file does not exist, write it to disk.

Currently I have:

```
m = re.compile(r'(ts|js)config.json$')
for file in files:
    if m.search(file):
        return True
    else:
        self.writeFile()
```

Which works, but it calls write multiple times when there is not match.
How would I only call write after the checks are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just unindent your `else` block so it applies to `for`:

```
for file in files:
    if m.search(file):
        return True
else:
    self.writeFile()
```

note that in that case it's not as interesting as with the `break` case, you could simply write:

```
for file in files:
    if m.search(file):
        return True
self.writeFile()
```

since if pattern matches it returns so `writeFile` is not reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could move out writing the file to after all the checks are exhausted:

```
m = re.compile(r'(ts|js)config.json$')
for file in files:
    if m.search(file):
        return True

self.writeFile()
```